# Uploadify get file size in MB

Tags: uploadify, filesize

I've surfed all internet but I didn't found answer in my question. I need to add file size in MB to the object, which I'm getting after upload:

```
Object[span.fileinfo]
```

so the file size should be inserted in to this span with other data. I'm using uploadify html5 version (uploadfive).

after upload I'm getting this info:

> filename.ext

into this template:

```
'itemTemplate' : '<p class="files uploadifive-queue-item"><i class="ico close" style="cursor: pointer;" title="Panaikinti"></i><span class="filename"></span><span class="fileinfo"></span></p>'
```

does anyone know what should I do? And if is it possible?

Comment: You could use the `bytesloaded` event from [onProgress](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadifive/onprogress/)

Comment: could I get more info about that?

Comment: Not tested, I don't have uploadifive, but: `$('#element').uploadifive({'onProgress':function(){console.log(e.bytesloaded);}});` where the rest of your options are in that object too